# Bezier curve in f(x) form

Tags: function, graph, bezier

I'm trying to get a cubic bezier curve (four points) implementation in f(x) form. Obviously bezier curves aren't perfect functions, but if the last two points are within a square made between the first and second point then they are. I'm really not that great with maths - I barely understand the implementation of a normal bezier curve, and I have no idea how or if you can equate things together to get such a function. i.e. y = f(x).

That being said, I don't necessarily need a bezier curve, I just need a curve that goes from one point to another where I can define the gradients at both points. I've tried to mess around with mathematics to get such a function, and I managed to get a function which drives at the appropriate gradients, but not the appropriate height.

> y = m1*x^2 / 2w + w(m1 - m2*x/2)

This function has (0,0) with gradient = m1

and (w, y) gradient = m2

The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the height between the two points into the equation. I had a method for another equation, where the new function was f(x) * h / f(w), but in this case that changes the gradients of the points in question.

Answer (score 1):

Bezier spline is a parametric function of `t` and control points (four in case of cubic Bezier spline)

`P(t) = f(t, P1, P2, P3, P4)`

More precisely for 2D case:

```
    x(t) = (1 - t)^3*x1 + 3*(1 -  t)^2*t*x2 + 3*(1 -  t)*t^2*x3 + t^3*x4
    y(t) = (1 - t)^3*y1 + 3*(1 -  t)^2*t*y2 + 3*(1 -  t)*t^2*y3 + t^3*y4
```

where `t in [0, 1]`.

It will be hard to express y(t) through x(t) as it's multiple-valued function in general case.